# Azure DevOps Build with lots of dependencies

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cicd

Hi Azure DevOps experts.
We finished the migration of our code from svn to git and want to automate as much as possible with azure devops pipelines.
We have already made lots of pipelines for all our libs and build them when there is a check-in on the master branch.

But when it comes to propagate changes from some libs to the end-product it gets complicated.
Below an simplified example of our project/repo structure in Azure DevOps:

Project Tools:

- Logger Lib
- Tools Lib
- Telnet Lib

Project Supplier Libs:

- Library Supplier 1

  - Consumes Logger Lib
  - Consumes Tools Lib
- Library Supplier 2

  - Consumes Logger Lib
  - Consumes Telnet Lib
- Library Supplier 3

  - Consumes Logger Lib
  - Consumes Tools Lib

Project Product 1:

- Library Product 1

  - Consumes Library Supplier 1
  - Consumes Library Supplier 2
  - Consumes Library Supplier 3
  - Consumes
- Service Exe

  - Consumes Library Product 1

What would be the best way to implement this Build in Azure Pipelines?

Lets say I have a change in Tools Lib.

At the moment every Lib has its own build pipeline.
To get the changes to Service Exe we would need to make following steps after a check-in to Tools Lib:

1. Build Tools (triggered after check-in on main branch) Lib and push Nuget package to global artifacts feed.
2. - Manually update Library 1

     - Build Library 1 (triggered after check-in on main branch) and push Nuget package to global artifacts feed
3. - Manually update Library 2

     - Build Library 2 (triggered after check-in on main branch) and push Nuget package to global artifacts feed
4. - Manually update Library 3

     - Build Library 3 (triggered after check-in on main branch) and push Nuget package to global artifacts feed
5. - Manually update Product Library 1

     - Build Product Library 1 (triggered after check-in on main branch) and push Nuget package to global artifacts feed
6. - Manually update Service Exe

     - Build Service Exe (triggered after check-in on main branch)
     - Build Service Exe Msi Package (triggered after check-in on main branch)

What would be the best practice to propagate this change so that it is finally used in Service Exe build pipeline?

Regards
meisterd

I played a bit around with dependabot. Should i use some Trigger that runs when tools is finished, then runs dependabot automatically and updates the nugets?
Or would it be better to checkout all sourcecode by using the other repos as resources and build alltogether in one pipeline as project with project references instead of nuget packages?

How is this done for much more complex projects with eg 75 libs that all have an inpact on the endproduct?

And finally are there any real world examples for really complex projects around?

Comment: You can set nuget references to `3.*` for example to automatically take the latest version of the available nuget. Then only in a release branch fix the versions to an exact version should you want to.